# How do I Select 2 Values of the same Attribute in SQL

Tags: sql, relational-division

I have 3 different tables, which contain:

```
suppliers (sid; sname; adress)
parts(pid; pname; color)
catalog (sid; pid; cost)
```

Now I have to get the SIDs of the suppliers, who supply a red part and a green part.

And the result should be the following:

```
SID      Color1      Color2
---      ---------   ------
S1       green       red
```

I don't understand, what I have to do, to select 2 values of the same attribute `Color`. Do I have to use a sub-Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to get two *columns*, you'd have to join the products table twice. While this would work, it does not scale (imagine you have to extend to 10 different colours...).

So the above answer of Gordon Linoff works and will return each color in a separate row, with the same `sid`, like so:

```
SID  Color
---  -----
S1   red
S1   green
```

to get it in two colums (if you really want to do this):

```
SELECT s.sid, p1.color, p2.color
FROM suppliers s
JOIN cataglog c ON c.sid=s.sid
JOIN products p1 ON p1.pid=c.pid
LEFT JOIN products p2 ON p2.pid=c.pid AND p2.color != p1.color
GROUP BY s.sid
```

LEFT JOIN the second products table, for the case that there is no secondary color.

Again, this is ugly and does not scale, I'd suggest to go with a multi-row solution.

Comment: Its part of my exam preperation, it was a task in an older exam and i couldnt find any solutions to that, so thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select s.sid
from suppliers s join
     catalog c
     on s.sid = c.sid join
     products p
     on c.pid = p.id
where p.color in ('green', 'red')
group by s.id
having count(distinct p.color) = 2;
```

Comment: Ah thanks, but if i want the output to show Select s.sid, Color1, Color2, how can i achieve that?

Comment: @Sheriff_Joe . . . You can add `min(color) as color1, max(color) as color2`.  However, that seems utterly superfluous, because you know every `sid` returned has both colors.